# Is it necessary to deploy .cs and designer.cs files in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, hosting

Is it Necessary to Deploy the .cs and .designer.cs files of .aspx page while transferring the files through FTP to Deployment sever?
Or Does the application dll can takes care of it?

Comment: Not only is deploying them unnecessary, it also potentially breaches your organization's intellectual property protection and reveals code security issues (such as hard-coded keys).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No that isn't necessary, the `.cs` and `.designer.cs` files are compiled into a `.dll` file for deployment.

More info can be find in this article:

[Determining What Files Need to Be Deployed (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/determining-what-files-need-to-be-deployed-cs)

Answer (score 5):

The DLLs and the aspx pages should be the only thing you need to deploy. `.designer` and `.cs` files are for you to continue development.